# How do I convert objects created in Graal JavaScript to serializable Java objects

Tags: javascript, java

I am using graal/javascript 21.3.6 to create a Java object (call it MySerializable) using JavaScript.  The resulting Java object needs to be fully serializable.  The Java constructor takes a Map passed in from JavaScript/Graal.  The passed in Map is a PolyglotMap instance, which is not serializable and contains non-serializable objects.  In the MySerializable constructor I can call back to Graal to convert the PolyglotMap to something else, but I'm having real trouble finding out how to do this.  Note the PolyglotMap and PolyglotWrapper (its interface) are all package protected so I can't use any of their methods.  Also, during the MySerializable constructor, I do not have access to the Context object used to run the script.

As an illustration, here is some pseudo-code:

```js
   var MySerializable = Java.type("MySerializable");
   var SomeOtherClass = Java.type("SomeOtherClass");
   var config = { "a" : 1, "b" : SomeOtherClass() }
   var x = MySerializable(config)
```

```java
public class SomeOtherClass implements Serializable {
   public SomeOtherClass() { }
}

public class MySerializable implements Serializable {

   HashMap serializableConfig ;

   public MySerializable(Map config) {
        this.serializableConfig = MakeSerializable(config);
   }
```

How can I implement the MakeSerializable() method above?